# How to get custom post type posts with certain multiple tags names and category id?

Tags: query-posts

Here is my query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'tag' => $searchval,
    'paged' => $paged
); 
query_posts($args);
```

But this not working.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the source of your variables *and* your complete debug information.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended NOT to use query_posts() function as this can affect a LOT of different things.

While this question is especially difficult to answer when you don't specify how it's not working and the source of your variables, the better way to formulate this query would be by using the filter entitled ['pre_get_posts'](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJzuS8r_XTAhVIVyYKHVzsDCEQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FPlugin_API%2FAction_Reference%2Fpre_get_posts&usg=AFQjCNGqrm7Iu558AtjXbbFNdaE2xiqGxg).

Example:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_267038_jobs_posts' );
function wpse_267038_jobs_posts( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'jobs' );
        $query->set( 'cat', $category_id );
        $query->set( 'tag', $searchval );
        $query->set( 'paged', $paged );
    }
}
```

While we can't check to be sure that achieves the proper results because of your lack of details, this is the way to go about it.